# Using Mongodb Adapter in NextAuth not working

Tags: mongodb, material-ui, next.js, adapter, next-auth

I git clone & copy MUI [Nextjs example project](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs) & start from there.

From NextAuth portal, they said I can just copy mongodb adapter setup [here](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/mongodb) and basically it will work well out of the box. I placed this file in this path: `/src/lib/mongodb.js`

Here I'm using `CredentialsProvider`. Basically I'm using my own `form` for `login` & `authentication` process.

Here my `/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js` file:

```
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter";
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import clientPromise from "../../../src/lib/mongodb";

export default NextAuth({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const { email, password } = credentials

        if(email !== 'test@test.com' || password !== 'password123') {
          throw new Error('User does not exists. Please make sure you insert the correct email & password.')
        }

        return {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Tester',
          email: 'test@test.com'
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    redirect: async ({ url, baseUrl }) => {
      return baseUrl
    }
  }
})
```

What I understood, I can just straight away use this adapter & it will **create 4 models/tables (User, Session, Account, VerificationToken) by default**. So I don't need to create them myself. Ref doc [here](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/models)

According to the [NextAuth MongoDB Adapter documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/mongodb), I just need to specify the `MONGODB_URI` in `.env.local`.

so here my `/.env.local` file content:

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@rest.lvnpm.mongodb.net/<database_name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
SECRET=someSecret
NODE_ENV=development
```

**So currently, it does nothing at all**. I don't need to specify `session.strategy` to `database` since by default NextAuth will recognized that if I use `adapter` option.

What do I need to do here to make this work? Any helps is appreciated. [Here my github project](https://github.com/lalapolalaanewb/nextjs_mongodbAdapter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that in NextAuth, if I use `CredentialsProvider`. I won't be able to persist data using database strategy. You may go [here](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials) to NextAuth documentation itself to know why